How to limit how often a job can run in Jenkins pipeline (groovy) using Throttle feature
What is the syntax to get the throttle feature in my Jenkinsfile?
In the Jenkins UI it looks like this: (see image)
I have a job set to run twice a week. The job runs for about 1 day (heavy database queries).
It runs for hours then fails due to database issues, so often it will take 2-3 days for it to succeed.  In that case by the time it finally finishes, sometimes the next scheduled run is already scheduled, so it runs again.  I don't want it to run again, I want to limit it to not run more than once every 3 days.  I always do this in Jenkins using the throttle feature but I can't find documentation of how to implement it in the Jenkinsfile (pipeline).  I am not looking for other solutions, I know I can solve it other ways, I just want to know how to use the throttle feature in the Jenkinsfile and Google is not bringing me any answers.

There is no image...

You are right, it's very poorly documented, but it is documented partially here. Why it is under the workflow-multibranch plugin and in properties section - I don't know. The implementation is in branch-api. In any case, here is the syntax:
options {
    rateLimitBuilds(throttle: [count: 10, durationName: 'month', userBoost: true])
}

